# Geographical assignment of input data to consumers, based on business-defined areas

Tags: maps

I want to deliver some products to some agencies based on their geographical locations in a city. This is the business requirement:

Business people should be able to define areas inside a city. These areas can overlap, and can be in any shapes. The information of these areas should be stored in a database. Also a facility (like Google Maps My Maps) should be used so that they can CRUD those areas easily.

There is a list of agencies with their positions on the map (latitude and longitude).

Each agency chooses which area(s) he wants to work in.

We collect some data from people (ordinary people), and we should be able to AUTOMATICALLY assign an area to each data. In other words, the data is geographical, and we should be able to determine if data item is within the borders of a specified area or not.

Then based on these prerequisites, we deliver our products to agencies.

I don't know if I could explain it in simple terms or not, but I hope that it's OK.

ASMAIK Google Maps (my maps) lets people draw areas. This is really really really cool. But I can't find a utility anywhere which tells me if a specified point on Google Maps is within an area or not. Yes, we can find out this by our eyes, as a point is located inside an area or outside it. But we want to make this automatic.

So, does Google Maps have this feature? If not, can you suggest me the required software? I'm a full-stack web developer, working with C# and SQL Server in the backend.

Comment: take a look at http://conference.scipy.org/scipy2013/tutorial_detail.php?id=110